# Virtualbox start problem

Tags: 11.04, virtualbox

[image: virtual box error]

hi, I have problem with Virtualbox as I installed from USC in Natty. but, I have installed **virtualbox-ose-dkms** what wrong? see picture.

Comment: Does `lsmod | grep vboxdrv` show anything? If not, try running `sudo modprobe vboxdrv`.

Comment: You can also try to run 'sudo /etc/init.d/vbroxdrv setup'.

Comment: thanks user6053. I try `sudo modprobe vboxdrv` success

Answer (score 3):

run

```
sudo /etc/init.d/vboxdrv setup
```

The either reboot or run

```
sudo modprobe vboxdrv
```